# How to sum float django

Tags: python, django, sum

I've got a problem with sum float. I've got some Gadget Object, which is filter by gadget, because there are two gadgets which measures energy.
Here is my code:

```
for gadget n gadget:
d={}  
 ['energy']=Gadget.objects.filter(gadget=gadget).aggregate(energy=Avg(    'energy'))['energy'] or '0.00' 

s = GadgetDay.objects.filter(gadget=gadget)
l = []
for log in s:
            l.append(log.energy)
```

When I print l, it gives me two list with floats. When I try to sum this:
    k = sum(l)
it returned me two floats. When I want to append this to next list, it returned me two list with floats again. Gadget and GadgetDay in models are abstract class. How can I sum all floats?

Comment: Please show us the list you are getting. How you are getting two lists, when appending to one?

Comment: Also `sum` returning two values seems unlikely.

Comment: There are lists: [52.47, 53.16] - energy from gadget A and [0.0, 49.21] - energy from gadget B

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing calculation at python level, you can do it using Django's ORM using `.aggregate()`.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

>>> Gadget.objects.filter(gadget=gadget).aggregate(total_energy=Sum('energy'))

{'total_energy': 12345.67}
```

The above query returns `Sum()` of all `energy` Field in the the queryset.

Read more about: [aggregation queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: This method returns two dictionary: {'total_energy': 105.63}
{'total_energy': 49.21} for every gadget

Comment: What `Field()` is your `energy` field?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand

Comment: How did you define energy field in your models? _like `energy = models.FooField(...`_

Comment: I don't define energy in model, I create this in views:                                          for gadget in gadget:
        d={}
        d['energy'] = Gadget.objects.filter(gadget=gadget,).aggregate(energy=Avg('energy'))['energy'] or '0.00'

Comment: update the question with appropriate details.